# PHP Curl duplicating request

Tags: php, curl

The Curl request is being duplicated. What I noticed is that the duplicated request is always sent without the user/pass, maybe this is a hint to what the issue is.

```
$user = 'xx';
$pass = 'xx';
$URL = 'xx';

$ch = curl_init()
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'env: DEV',
    'TransactionID: ' . $tr_id,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the "duplicate" HTTP request is sent exactly by _this_ block of code and that the same code is not called twice?

Comment: I am almost positive. Also if the code was being called twice then it would insert the user/pass in both calls.

Comment: Not a fact. I would either run a debugger with a break point set on `curl_exec`, or put some `trigger_error("[URL] $URL [user] $user [pass] $pass" . (new \Exception())->getTraceAsString(), E_USER_NOTICE)` before `curl_exec` to find out more information about the source of the call.

Comment: With `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH: CURLAUTH_ANY`, you are allowing cURL to “test” several HTTP Auth methods, maybe that is the reason here? If you know which particular HTTP Auth method the remote party uses here upfront, then try and explicitly specify that one instead.

Comment: @CBroe it appears that was the issue. changed CURLAUTH_ANY to  CURLAUTH_BASIC      thanx,  have a great evening :)